# Why I can't create a file in pictures library successfully based on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In my WP Silverlight 8.1 App, the following codes would throw a UnauthorizedAccessException, and tell me that Access is denied, but it works very well on Universal Apps.

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("mytest.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Is the capability required declared in your Package.appxmanifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the pictures library on Windows Phone 8.1 you must have the following capability in your package.appxmanifest file:

```
<Capabilities>
 <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that you already have enabled ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO, my guess is that in WP81 Silverlight you need to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary.SavePicture.

Comment: Microsoft.Xna is not available for 8.1 apps.

Comment: Does Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app support KnownFolders API?

Comment: Thank you Claus for the comment. I just checked and I was able to create a Windows PHONE (!) 8.1 SILVERLIGHT (!) project in VS2013 which creates an instance of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary().

Comment: Really? In my VS Express 2013, with my steps as following: FILE->New Project->Choose Templates/Visual C#/Store Apps/Windows Phone Apps/Black App, I can't create a MeidaLibrary instance in this project, because IDE doesn't recognize Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary at all.

Comment: I don't have "Black App" (or anything which would translate from this into German). However I have e.g. "Pivot App (Windows Phone Silverlight)". The "Silverlight" part is important, simply because your thread title says "Silverlight" as well. If you select "... (Windows Phone)" instead, then this implies WindowsRuntime and XNA is indeed not available.